# How to create new Row Labels in PivotTable with data from olapcube with vba?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, olap

I have a `PivotField` which will be a `RowField`. It contains dates in the format `dddd, mmmm dd yyyy` probably as `string`, because I was unable to filter the date with `.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueIsBetween` or `.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween`, etc. If you want to know my journey to this conclusion, you will find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151962/filter-for-dates-which-are-in-caption-in-pivottables-which-come-from-olap-cube) .

Now my new plan is to create a new `RowLabel` which has the date in `Double` format and then filter there for the date.

With the following code it works really well to convert this `long` format into the `double` format and I can just overwrite the `i.Caption` value. However the `.PivotFilters.Add` won't work with this configuration also.

```
For Each i In .PivotItems
    Debug.Print i.Caption        'in Format dddd, mmmm dd yyyy 
    p = i.Caption
    u = Split(p, ",")(1)
    Debug.Print CDate(u)         'e.g. 04/09/2017
    i.Caption = CDbl(CDate(u))   'here should be the new RowLabel which should be filled               
 Next i
```

Comment: You say you were unable to filter the date with .PivotFilters.Add.  Fire up the macro recorder, set the DateBetween filter manually, then take a look at the code it recorded.  When I did it, I got this:

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("[Range].[Date].[Date]"). _
        PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:="1/02/2017", Value2:= _
        "1/08/2017"

Note that the macro recorder didn't care that the dates were formatted in dddd, mmmm dd yyyy format...it just used the d/mm/yyyy format appropriate for my location (New Zealand).